# Java Jar: Specifying independent filepaths

Tags: java, jar

So, at work, we have a java application that we license to clients. Frequently, our clients require very specific things that we don't want in the core product, so we make those changes, package them in a jar, and place the jar in the libs directory of the branch in our VCS that we use for that client.

We want to start packaging the .java files in the jar along with the .class files, just as an extra backup for our source code. The thing is, in our main codebase, all our .class files are in a filetree starting at a folder called "out", and all our .java files are in a filetree starting at a folder called "development".

So, I don't want the folder that's unique to both of them to be where I run the jar command from the command line. The reason for this is the jar utility builds a folder structure that mirrors what it sees when it builds the jar, and I need my folder structure to start at com.companyname.etc... for the class file.

Is there any way to specify totally divergent filepaths when creating a jar? Or to specify the folder structure that should be the destination when the files are dropped in the jar?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you need a build tool like Maven or Gradle to manage both your code paths and your dependencies.

Comment: How do you build your jar? If you are not using Ant, it might be the way to go, just tweak targets.xml to specify which file go to where? See [here](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html)for ant doc on jars